# How can I rename the servers names found in Screen Sharing "Open Recent...." menu?

Tags: macos, catalina, screen-sharing

I connect to a handful of macs via Screen Sharing. After connecting for the first time, the name and port are remembered by the app and are displayed at the "Open Recent..." menu.

While this is helpful, the displayed names are out of my control and sometimes make no sense to me or they are basically the same.

I would like to rename them to something that has a meaning to me. How can I do this?

Comment: I did a `grep -R` inside `~/Library` and I didn't find a thing.

Comment: Network names are not set locally, they are set by the Mac you connect to. You could create an alias, put them all in a folder in Documents, named as you want them and then put that folder in the Dock. Voila instant network menu named as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the *name(s)* shown in **Screen Sharing** > **Connection** > **Open Recent**, as in the image below, you'd edit the *filename(s)* in the following *location*:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.ScreenSharing/Data/Library/Application Support/Screen Sharing/
```

Files at this *location* are **XML plist** *files* having a **vncloc** *extension*.

With **Screen Sharing** closed, I changed the original *name* from what it was to what's shown in the image. When I opened **Screen Sharing** the renamed **vncloc** *file* showed as is.

[image]

Comment: I had grep'ed for all files in ~/Library/ for the name of the server. I never thought about searching for files called _like_ the server, haha. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While it seems to be impossible to change Screen Sharing, you could simply create link files and put them in a folder.

The easiest way I could find on how to do this is to type the link in a text file (vnc://user@ip:port), select said text and drag it to the desktop. It will create a file that when clicked will open Screen Sharing.

Thanks to Steve Chambers for the idea.

Comment: RE: "While it seems to be impossible to change Screen Sharing" -- It **is not** impossible to change the names of items that show on the Screen Sharing > Connection > Open Recent menu. See my answer to your question for details.